# cannot use GLEW on 64bit windows 7

Tags: opengl, 64-bit, glew

I downloaded both 32 and 64bit versions and copied dll and lib files into corresponding folders(system32, systemWOW64, vc\lib and vc\lib\armd64). 
I can build the project to both win32 and x64 platform but failed to run the executable with error “the application was unable to start correctly(0xc000007b)”.

However, when I commented the sentence "GLenum err = glewInit();" and rebuild it, things go just right. so what's wrong with my glew installation? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you link to *different* GLEW import libraries for your 64-bit build than your 32-bit one? Also, stop putting stuff in your Visual Studio directories.

Comment: Check if you have done everything like here.http://www.courses.fas.harvard.edu/~lib175/pages/visstudio.html

Comment: I find a workaround by using GLFW, which spent me a lot of time in environment configuration too, instead of creating windows myself. Thank you guys for your reply.

Comment: @NicolBolas I fixed it by putting dll into my porject file, thank you.